# How to send array of object in post request using axios library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I need to insert data as multiple rows using an array of the javascript object.

props.email is held an array such as

```
props.email = [
{email: 'najathi@email.com', name: 'najathi'},
{email: 'naharni@email.com', name: 'naharni'},
]

axios.post('/create-email.php', props.email, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Comment: user ``JSON.stringify()``, to convert your array of objects to a string, then send data to your backend.

Comment: Error occurred..
POST https://../create-email.php 400
Error: Request failed with status code 400

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```js
const payload = {
  email:[
          {email: 'najathi@email.com', name: 'najathi'},
          {email: 'naharni@email.com', name: 'naharni'},
      ]
}

axios.post('/create-email.php', payload, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
    }
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: `axios.post()` returns a response object. To get data from response you need write the next code 
`.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
})`

Comment: Error occurred..
POST https://../create-email.php 400
Error: Request failed with status code 400

Comment: Try adding the header for 'Content-Type'.  I have updated the answer. :)

Comment: this is not supported 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'

Comment: it only supports  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: I have successfully added one row of data but I have to add the multiple rows in an array of objects